# unable to reference System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration

Tags: entity-framework-6.1

I need to add System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration to get DbContext. So when I searched online I found that I need to add reference to the dll EntityFramework.dll. I could not find the binary. Where is it located ?

I have latest Entity Framework installed on my machine. I have downloaded it from:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/C/F/2CF7AFAB-4068-4DAB-88C6-CEFD770FAECD/EFTools6.1.1ForVS2013.msi

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. I had to re-install it. CommandLine re-installation did not help. I used the wizard. Right click on your project and choose "Manage NuGet Packages". Select the Online --> nuget.org. It will get latest things on nuget.org. Choose EntityFramework and click install.

Comment: Yes. If EntityFramework already installed, force uninstall from Package Manager Command prompt and Install again by Right Click on project and choose  "Manage NuGet Packages" and Install EntityFramework. This works fine.